# Selenium Webdriver Headless Mode shows blank page

Tags: google-chrome, automation, webdriver, headless

I've been spending the past 2 hours trying to find out why the headless mode screws up my program.
When I disable the Headless mode, everything works fine and I can run the program without problems, however when (--headless) is enabled, my webdriver cant find any elements, since the page is just blank.

I would really appreciate some help, I guess the website is detecting the headless mode and therefor showing a blank page? Is there any way to bypass that?

Here is the list of Arguments im passing my browser:

```
options.AddArguments("--headless");
options.AddArguments("disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
options.AddArguments("log-level=3");
options.AddArguments("--windows-Size=1920,1080");
options.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.AddArguments("--disable-extensions");
options.AddArguments("--start-maximized");
options.AddArguments("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36");
```

Did you guys ever encounter that? I found some threads where the issue has been described before, but I couldnt find any solutions..

Thanks :)

Comment: Another day passed and I cant figure it out, really depressing..

Answer (score 0):

I had same your issue and resolved it by below solution

1. Get userAgent of browser first:

`String userAgent = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return navigator.userAgent;");`

`System.setProperty("useragent",userAgent);`

2. Add it to browser option as below

`options.addArguments("--user-agent="+System.getProperty("useragent"));`